# How to run a command for each subdirectory with a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, autotools

I have the following structure:

```
├── configure.ac
├── dir1
│   └── Makefile.am
├── dir2
│   └── Makefile.am
├── Makefile.am
...
```

`configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([amhello], [1.0], [bug-report@address])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Wall -Werror])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
    Makefile
    dir1/Makefile
    dir2/Makefile
])

# Libtool
AM_PROG_AR
LT_INIT

AM_EXTRA_RECURSIVE_TARGETS([foo])

AC_OUTPUT
```

The top-level `Makefile.am`

```
SUBDIRS = dir1 dir2

foo-start:
    @echo "executing foo!"
    make foo
```

Both `dir1` and `dir2` `Makefile.am`'s look like this:

```
foo-local:
    echo "I'm here! $$(basename $(CURDIR))"
```

Running this yields the output like this:

```
execute foo!
I'm here! dir1
I'm here! dir2
```

Is there a way to write the subdirectory's Makefiles so that I don't have to write the foo-local task twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to write the subdirectory's Makefiles so that I don't have to write the foo-local task twice?

You can put the rule that you want to duplicate among your subdirectory Makefiles in its own file, and use Automake's [`include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Include.html#index-include-1) feature to incorporate it by reference into each of the subdirectory makefiles.

`(source tree root)/subdir-common.am`

```
foo-local:
    echo "I'm here! $$(basename $(CURDIR))"
```

`(source tree root)/dir*/Makefile.am`

```
include $(top_srcdir)/subdir-common.am
```

That doesn't win you much in the example presented, but presumably that's a model of something more complicated that you want to do, where you may benefit from avoiding repetition.

Note that there is nothing special about the `.am` extension for the name of the included file.  I use it for its value as a mnemonic, but it is not inherently meaningful to the Autotools.